# Injecting one MockBean into another

Tags: spring, mocking, junit5

I have a typical SpringApplication which I am trying to test via MockMvc. The application contains some database calls and some thridparty api calls, and I want to mock all of them, while testing end to end flow, except thirdparty

This is what I have created -

Controller class

```
public class PortfolioController {

private final PortfolioService portfolioService;
}
```

Service Class

```
public class PortfolioService {

private final PortfolioTransactionRepository portfolioTransactionRepository;
private final AlphavantageService alphavantageService;
}
```

AlphaVantageService

```
public class AlphavantageService {

private ApiConfig apiConfig;

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public Map<String, List<Candle>> getStockQuotes(List<String> symbols) {
    return symbols.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(symbol -> symbol, symbol -> getQuotes(symbol)));
}
}
```

Now comes the test -

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = PortfolioController.class)
class PortfolioControllerTest {

private List<PortfolioTransaction> transactions;

@MockBean
private AlphavantageService alphavantageService;

@MockBean
private PortfolioService portfolioService;

@Autowired
private PortfolioController portfolioController;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

The problem is, when I try to execute any mvc call on server, `AlphaVantageService` is not injected inside `PortfolioService`, so till level1, I get the beans injected, but on further levels, I dont get the same.

Is it by design or I am missing something? How should we test such test-cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually After trying some options here and there, I found a solution.

Just like `@MockBean`, spring also have a notion called `@SpyBean`. That solved my problem. So now my test looks like below

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = PortfolioController.class)
@MockBeans(value = {@MockBean(AlphavantageService.class), 
@MockBean(PortfolioTransactionRepository.class)})
@SpyBeans(value = {@SpyBean(PortfolioService.class)})
class PortfolioControllerTest {

private List<PortfolioTransaction> transactions;

@Autowired
private AlphavantageService alphavantageService;

@Autowired
@SpyBean
private PortfolioService portfolioService;

@Autowired
private PortfolioController portfolioController;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

This works like a charm and I can use full fledged dependency Injection in the tests.